# возвратить массив из пар дружественных чисел

Tags: javascript, теория-чисел

Необходимо реализовать функцию которая подсчитывает дружественные числа в заданном диапазоне,
Сигнатура функции - `getFriendlyNumbers(start, end)`

> start - начало диапазона
>       end - конец диапазона

Функция должна возвращать массив из пар дружественных чисел.
Например:

1. Для диапазона от 1 до 300 функция должна вернуть [[220, 284]]
2. Для диапазона от 1 до 100 функция должна вернуть пустой массив. []
3. Для диапазона от 284 до 500 функция должна вернуть пустой массив. []
4. Для диапазона от 1 до 1211 функция должна вернуть [[220, 284], [1184,
   1210]]
5. И так далее по диапазонам.

В случае, если переданы не правильные аргументы (неправильный тип данных (только числа!), `start > end`, отрицательный диапазон, дробные числа), функция должна вернуть `false`.
Числа должны находится в правильном порядке. `[284, 220]` - неправильно. Пары дружественных чисел не должны повторяться. `[[220, 284], [284, 220]]` - неправильно.

У меня напросилось следующее решение

```
var mas = [];
function getFriendlyNumbers(start, end) {
    if (
        !isNaN(parseFloat(start)) &&
        isFinite(start) &&
        !isNaN(parseFloat(end)) &&
        isFinite(end) &&
        start <= end &&
        start > 0 &&
        end > 0
    ) {
        while (start < end) {

            var sum1 = getDivSum(start);
            var sum2 = getDivSum(end);

            if (start == sum2 && end == sum1) {
                mas.push(sum2, sum1);

                return mas;
            } else {
                return mas;
            }

            start++;
        }
    } else {
        return [];
    }

}
function getDivSum(num) {
    return getSum(getDivisors(num));
}
function getDivisors(num) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
function getSum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Но почему-то не проходит тест даже 1, 1. В чём проблема?

Comment: У Вас функция гарантированно завершает работу на первой же итерации цикла `while`, до `start++` дело никогда не доходит. Потом, функция должна возвращать массив массивов, а у Вас возвращает одномерный массив чисел. И, к слову, где тут вот эта часть из условия - _"функция должна вернуть false"_?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFriendlyNumbers(start, end) {
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(start)) &&
    isFinite(start) &&
    !isNaN(parseFloat(end)) &&
    isFinite(end) &&
    start <= end &&
    start > 0 &&
    end > 0
  ) {
    var result = [];
    var sumI, sumJ;

    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
      sumI = getSumDivisor(i);
      for (var j = i + 1; j <= end; j++) {
        sumJ = getSumDivisor(j);
        if (sumI == j && sumJ == i) {
          result.push([sumJ, sumI]);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  return false;
}

function getSumDivisor(num) {
  var arr = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    sum += item;
  })
  return sum;
}
```